# Find particular file from extension from particular directory

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, shell-script

I want to find a particular filename from a particular directory.

Also I don't know the file name on that particular directory. I only know the extension of that file i.e.  ".uploaded".
So using that .uploaded extension i want to find the filemane.

I want the file name in output without full path up to the particular directory, I just want filename.

So how can i do?

Comment: Please include an actual example. It is really difficult to understand what you want at the moment, but an example is usually sufficient to explain such a task.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the path to the file by rev-cut-rev:

```
ls dir/*.uploaded | rev | cut -d/ -f1 | rev
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample directory structure:

```
$ ls -1 test
a
b.uploaded
c.uploaded
d.uploaded
e
```

With `find`, suitable for piping through to another command via `xargs`:

```
$ EXT='.uploaded'; find dir -maxdepth 1 -name "*$EXT" -exec basename {} "$EXT" \;
d
b
c
```

In shell script, using `basename` to strip directory and suffix:

```
$ EXT=".uploaded"; for i in dir/*"$EXT"; do basename -- "$i" "$EXT"; done
b
c
d
```

In shell script, using parameter expansion:

```
$ EXT=".uploaded"; for i in dir/*"$EXT"; do i=${i##*/}; printf '%s\n' "${i%$EXT}"; done
b
c
d
```

Note that you might hit several files. You have not defined what you want to happen after the file. If you are *sure* that there is only one file that will match, you can use `basename` directly:

```
$ rm dir/{b,d}.uploaded
$ basename dir/*.uploaded .uploaded
c
```

but this will fail if the glob matches multiple files.